# MySQL: dynamically swap "= :value" in query for "IS :value"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Sorry if there is some simple, **duh** solution I'm not seeing, but its the end of the day and my brain is tired. ;)

I perform a lot of queries where a variable passed to my (PDO)query function may either contain a value, or be `null`. 
But since you can't `=` for `null`, I have the problem that when I look for `col_a = 'something' AND col_b = 'something_else'` my query works fine, but when that second value is `null`, the same query fails: `col_a = 'something' AND col_b = null`. It should be `col_a = 'something' AND col_b IS null`.

What would be a good way to dynamically swap out that `=` for an `IS`?
So far the only solution I came up with is to search for the `=` and manually swap it out whenever I notice I'm adding a `null` value to the query (which would be possible in my `ReplaceParameters()` function which I use to emulate PDO param-replacement functionality for non-prepared queries).

However that just feels dirty and inefficient. I'd greatly appreciate your advice.

Comment: It is usually possible to construct the WHERE clause such that it accounts for null parameters (because you can compare IS NULL against any value, not just columns) with patterns like `WHERE ( col1 = ? OR ? IS NULL) AND  (col2 = ? OR ? IS NULL)` where each group receives the same parameter twice. This gets extremely out of hand when you have more than 2 or 3 parameters. How many input params would you expect to have?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski An example query would be the following: `$DATABASE->QuerySingleValue("SELECT id FROM filemanagement_imagecropped WHERE (image_id = :original_id AND x1y1 = :x1y1 AND x2y2 = :x2y2 AND aspect_ratio = :aspect_ratio);", ["original_id" => $originalImageID, "x1y1" => $x1y1, "x2y2" => $x2y2, "aspect_ratio" => $aspectRatio])`. In this scenario, `$aspectRatio` may be `null`, or it may be an actual value. And checking in the function where I make this call to not add the `aspect_ratio` param if it is `null` is undesireable: this situation happens 100's of times throughout the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. As I mentioned in my question I have a `ReplaceParameters()` function which I use to perform PDO-style parameter replacement for non-prepared queries.

In that function I already had the problem that calling `$this->m_connection->quote($value, PDO::PARAM_NULL)` replaces the param with `''` instead of `null` (so you get `my_column = ''` instead of `my_column = null`).

To fix that I added the regex
`$newQuery = preg_replace("/{$tempKey}\b/", "null", $newQuery);`
With a little modification I ended up with this:
`$newQuery = preg_replace(["/\s+=\s+{$tempKey}\b/", "/\s+(!=|<>)\s+{$tempKey}\b/"], [" IS null", " IS NOT null"], $newQuery);`
The first capture/replace pattern combination searches for `= :temp_key` and replaces it with `IS null`. The second capture/replace pattern searches for `!= :temp_key` and `<> :temp_key`, and replaces them with `IS NOT null`.

**Edit:** there is one extra thing I didn't account for in my solution above. The replacement of `=` `!=` `<>` with `IS null` and `IS NOT null` should **only** happen when it is within a `WHERE` clause. When actually setting values the syntax is still `SET my_column = null`.

I solved this by adding negative lookbehind to my regex to only replace parameters which are to the right of a `WHERE|where`:
`$newQuery = preg_replace(["/(?<=WHERE|where)(.*)\s*(?<!!)=\s+{$tempKey}/", "/(?<=WHERE|where)(.*)\s*(!=|<>)\s+{$tempKey}\b/"], ["$1 IS null", "$1 IS NOT null"], $newQuery);`
What's left then is the parameters which are not in a `WHERE|where` block. I couldn't come up with a good regex for that (it kept also matching unwanted parts), so I went for a simpler solution: find the index/position of the `WHERE` clause if it exists, and extract anything left of that as a substring, and replace the placeholders with `null`.

```
$whereIndex = stripos($newQuery, "WHERE");
if ($whereIndex !== false)
{
    $newQuery = substr_replace($newQuery, preg_replace("/{$tempKey}\b/", "null", substr($newQuery, 0, $whereIndex)), 0, $whereIndex);
}
else
{
    $newQuery = preg_replace("/{$tempKey}\b/", "null", $newQuery);
}
```

If anybody has a good idea for a regex-based solution to this last part, please do let me know.
If anyone wants me to explain my regex or something, again, just let me know.